# Getting href value in a deeply nested gallery

Tags: jquery, siblings

I'm having trouble finding ways to get the href value for the last child of a div. Basically, the layout is like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide1" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/1" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide2" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/2" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide3" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/3" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide4" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/4" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide5" class="slides"> 
       <a href="items/show/5" class="link"> <-- trying to get this href value
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the href value of the last sibling of ".link", but i can't. Point me where I did wrong please? So far, here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var latestUrl = $(".link").siblings(":last").attr("href");
console.log(latestUrl);
 });
```

but the console returns: "undefined"

[UPDATE] I've found the solution to this: I need to wait until the page loads everything, then only I can look for the href attribute of the last child. This example is a gallery of images, so it takes quite some time to load, probably a second after the page loads. So here is the code that sets a delay for the jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){
alert($('.link:last').attr("href"));
}, 3000);
</script>
```

This sets a 3-second delay. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the last `.slides` element. You could use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2cmpwsu/)

```
var latestUrl = $('#slider .slides:last').find('a').attr("href");
console.log(latestUrl);
```

---

Alternatively, this would work too:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/09oeqky6/)

```
var latestUrl = $('a', '#slider .slides:last').attr("href");
console.log(latestUrl);
```

---

While using `$('.link:last').attr('href')` may work given the HTML you provided, it wouldn't work if there was a `.link` element outside of `#slider`. In addition, it doesn't guarantee that it will be in the last `.slides` element.

Comment: Your example is working like it should, but I can't seem to get it work in the code itself.

Comment: ah, my mistake. this bit of code needs to be fired after the page finished loading.. so i've added 

`window.setTimeout(function(){
    alert($('.link:last').attr('href'));
    }, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

Should be as easy as `$('.link:last').attr('href')`

```js
alert($('.link:last').attr('href'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide1" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/1" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide2" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/2" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide3" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/3" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide4" class="slides">
       <a href="items/show/4" class="link">
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
    <div id="slide5" class="slides"> 
       <a href="items/show/5" class="link"> <-- trying to get this href value
           <h2>Date</h2>
           <h3>Title</h3>
       </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this works too, given that i put in setTimeout() before firing the code.