# Putting in a variable in href using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is relevant to this problem (which has been solved): [Previous Problem:Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553265/getting-href-value-in-a-deeply-nested-gallery/28553319), just to give context to the question.

What I want to do is to apply the link that I've got from the previous code, into a href in a button element. This is what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newestLink = "";
window.setTimeout(function(){
    var newLink = $('.link:last').attr("href");
    newestLink = newLink;
}, 1500);

window.setTimeout(function(){
alert(newestLink);
document.getElementById('#redButton').onClick = function() {
  document.getElementById('#redButton').href=newestLink;
}
}, 3000);
</script>
```

The `alert` code is just to check that I have the correct value. When I use this code, the console return an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null (anonymous function)`

I can't seem to understand where the code gone wrong. I'm following [this advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript).

Comment: take out the # on redButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use jQuery or the basic JavaScript Selector Style. If you mix them up this sort of typos can occur.

jQuery Style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newestLink = "";
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var newLink = $('.link:last').attr("href");
        newestLink = newLink;
    }, 1500);

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert(newestLink);
        var node = $('#redButton');
        node.click(function() {
            node.attr('href', newestLink);
        });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

A better way to do this then using some nasty timeouts is to use the ready event fired as soon as the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ // execute this code on ready
        var newLink = $('.link:last').attr('href');
        var node = $('#redButton');
        node.click(function() {
            node.attr('href', newestLink);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome code! I've used it and tweaked it a bit. I'm not using the DOM ready function because the page loads a picture gallery, which takes a bit of a time, and if i'm not mistaken DOM ready doesn't take into account images, right?

Comment: You can use $(window).load(function(){ ... }); instead of the ready event. Load should be triggered after the images are available.

Answer (score 3):

You mixed up javascript and jQuery syntax. Javascript is `document.getElementById('redButton')` and jQuery is `$('#redButton')`.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Rookie's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

please copy n paste below code work well in both chrome and mozilla without consol error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newestLink = "";
window.setTimeout(function(){
var newLink = $('.link:last').attr("href");
newestLink = newLink;
}, 1500);

window.setTimeout(function(){
alert(newestLink);
$("#redButton").click(function(e) {
    $(this).prop("href",newestLink);
});
}, 3000);
</script>
```